# C# Proper format of a Nested foreach loop?

Tags: c#, list, loops, foreach, nested

I need to traverse a list containing string sentences and find sentences which contain string words from another list and add them to a separate list for displaying purposes. The code below prints out the same sentence multiple times so I was wondering what the proper format of a nested foreach loop is?

```
 List<string> sentenceList = new List<string>();
        sentenceList.Add("Dog ate a bone");
        sentenceList.Add("Cat had a ball and bone");

        List<string> keywords = new List<string>();
        keywords.Add("bone");
        keywords.Add("Cat")

 List<string> NewList = new List<string>();

            foreach (string sentence in sentenceList)
            {
                foreach (string word in keywords)
                {
                    if (sentence.Contains(word))
                    {
                        NewList.Add(sentence);
                    }
                }
            }
```

**What I get as output:**

> Dog ate a bone
>
> Cat had a ball and bone
>
> Cat had a ball and bone

I want each sentence to appear only once obviously but why does it get repeated *twice*? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I gets repeated because the second sentence contains both keywords (bone and Cat).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is adding again because you are not checking that `sentence` already exists in list or not.

You can check if it already exists in it don't add it:

```
if (sentence.Contains(word))
{
  if(!NewList.Contains(sentence))
     NewList.Add(sentence);
}
```

your code:

```
foreach (string sentence in sentenceList)
{
   foreach (string word in keywords)
   {
      if (sentence.Contains(word))
      {
         if(!NewList.Contains(sentence))
            NewList.Add(sentence);
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In both sentences "bone" is the same word 
your keyword list should contain

```
List<string> keywords = new List<string>();
        keywords.Add("Dog"); // or  keywords.Add("ate")
        keywords.Add("Cat")
```

Comment: That does not solve the problem, If done right it should display both sentences once.